# Dissolve causes 'No Shapely geometry can be created from null value' in geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

When I do dissolve:

With this specific shapefile happens with other similar it is working fine.
Also I checked for null values in the geometry and there weren't any.

```
data2 = pst[pst['PROP_TYPE'].str.startswith(('01'))]
dslvd=data2.dissolve(by='PROP_TYPE')



TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 223630.72975008655 4405823.482638143 at 223630.72975008655 4405823.482638143
TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 223630.72975008655 4405823.482638143 at 223630.72975008655 4405823.482638143
TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 223630.72975008655 4405823.482638143 at 223630.72975008655 4405823.482638143


 No Shapely geometry can be created from null value

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you able to share the shapefile or to reconstruct a reproducible example?

Comment: file http://www.mediafire.com/file/0q9gm0l1qhpoqu1/PST.zip

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the Error says that your polygons do have a self intersection at the given coordinates, to avoid it you will have to reconstruct your polygons with a buffer.

```
data2['geometry'] = data2.buffer(0.01) # a small value that could be neglected only to create a non self intersecting polygon
```

and then run your dissolve function

Comment: In my case, buffer(0) often works. Which is even better because if you work with degrees, such as with WGS84, when you add 0.01 it's actually quite a lot

Comment: `.buffer(0.01)` changes the geometry, and is a poor-(wo)mans solution to the problem. Please use `make_valid` from `shapely.validation`.

Answer (score 3):

A self-intersecting polygon shouldn't be fixed by `.buffer(0.1)`, since this also changes the polygon's geometry and `0.01` might still be quite a buffer, e.g. when dealing with longitudes and latitudes. At the very least use `1e-15` or even `1e-16`. However, rather use `shapely.validation.make_valid`, since this will more like return what was intended. The problem only occurs when `dissolve` needs to combine more than 1 shape where one is self-intersecting, since combining only 1 shape, even if self-intersecting, is a trivial case.

Consider `self_intersecting` as defined below, the polygon looks like this:

[image: Self intersecting polygon]

Usually `make_valid` 'repairs' the polygon by returning a MultiPolygon or GeometryCollection, in this case a MultiPolygon with these children:

[image: MultiPolygon children]

It's still ambiguous whether the interior hole was intended or an artifact of numerical precision issues, however this is the most adequate fix.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.validation import make_valid


self_intersecting = Polygon([[-1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [-1, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1]])
diamond = Polygon([[-1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1]])

data = gpd.GeoDataFrame([
    {'name': 'silly shape', 'geometry': self_intersecting},
    {'name': 'silly shape', 'geometry': diamond}
])

# data['geometry'] = data['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x if x.is_valid else x.buffer(0))
data['geometry'] = data['geometry'].apply(make_valid)

data.dissolve('name')

data['geometry'].iloc[0]
```

Alternatively, you can opt to have the holes filled via `self_intersecting.buffer(0)` or `data['geometry'] = data['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x if x.is_valid else x.buffer(0))`

[image: filled solution]